# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target') & (reading 'value')

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, jquery-ui

*After JQuery Version Upgrades to 3.5.0 from 2.14, I am receiving the following error, but I did not fully understand what the problem is,there is radio = event.target The error I received in the definition of Cannot Read Properties of Undefined (Reading 'target')
Anyone can you help me solve?**

```js
var testMethod = {
    testSubMethod: function (event) {
    
        var radio = event.target;
        var isMultiInput = $('#MultipleInputYes').is(':checked');

   
        if (!isMultiInput || radio.value == undefined) {
            $('.divMultiInput').addClass("dp-none");

            if (radio.value == 'false') {
                $('#divInputValueType').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#divInputValueType').attr('style', '');
            }

  
        }
    },
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio radio-success">
<input type="radio" id="MultipleInputYes" value="true" name="IsMultiInput" onchange="testMethod.testSubMethod(this)">
<label for="MultipleInputYes"> Yes</label>
</div>

<div class="radio radio-success">
<input type="radio" id="MultipleInputNo" value="false" checked="checked" name="IsMultiInput" onchange="testMethod.testSubMethod(this)">
<label for="MultipleInputNo">No</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`testMethod.testSubMethod(this)` **this** - referenced to html object in you case.

So probably changing

```
testSubMethod: function (event) {
    var radio = event.target;
```

to something like this may fix your problem

```
testSubMethod: function (el) {
    var radio = el;
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive `event` must be undefined in

```javascript
var radio = event.target;
```

so that when you try to access `event.target` you are accessing `target` property of `undefined` which is an error in javascript
try checking if event is defined first

```javascript
var radio = event ? event.target : undefined
```

Comment: all right, this is also a method solution